# from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry, fromstr ImportError: cannot import name GEOSException

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am working on django-oscar project to create custom eCommerce application.

When i run my project using `python manage.py runserver` command, 
I got  this error "

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry, fromstr
    ImportError: cannot import name GEOSException"
```

How to install GEOS?

Answer (score 3):

To use the geospatial functionality of django, you need to additionally install the related libraries:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/